# Clear sinon stub after test

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, stub

I have this stub in one of my tests:

```
sinon.stub(service, 'batchNote')
    .resolves(mResponse);
```

Is it possible to clear it down after the test? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible.

`Sinon` API have `restore` method for `stubs`. From the [docs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.4.1/stubs/)

> The original function can be restored by calling `object.method.restore()`; (or `stub.restore()`)

So using your example you could simply do:

```
const stub = sinon.stub(service, 'batchNote');
stub.resolves(mResponse);

console.log(service.batchNote()); // outputs stubbed value

stub.restore()
console.log(service.batchNote()); // outputs original
```