# Unable to mock event handler on test

Tags: javascript, sinon

So i have a very simple class which does the following:

- Adds an event handler on an element on it's creation
- The event handler is an instance method of the class
- I need a `cleanup` method to remove the handler on demand

```js
export default class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    this.element = document.getElementById("test");
    this.element.addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler);
  }

  clickHandler(e) {
    console.log("Click handler called");
  }

  cleanup() {
    this.element.removeEventListener("click", this.clickHandler);
  }
}
```

And i have a test where i [stub](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) the handler (i need to change it's behavior) and make some checks.

```js
describe("Test", function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    this.instance = new TestClass();
    this.clickHandlerStub = sinon.stub(this.instance, "clickHandler");
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    this.instance.cleanup();
    delete this.instance;
  });

  it("test case", function () {
    document.getElementById("test").click();
    expect(this.clickHandlerStub.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

The expected behavior is to `stub` (override) the handler (so no logging should appear) and my expectation should pass since it should be called once when the element is clicked.
However it seems that it keeps logging and the expectation fails.

If i change the way i bind the event handler and use an arrow function everything works fine.

```js
this.element.addEventListener("click", () => this.clickHandler());
```

But then i can't remove the event handler in my `cleanup` method since `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` need to pass the same handler reference in order to work properly.

I created a [reproducable example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mocha-unit-test-example-forked-dozr4?file=/src/index.js) in case it's helpful.

So what am i missing here?

Comment: The codesandbox was very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `stub` `TestClass`'s *prototype*.

```
this.clickHandlerStub = sinon
  .stub(TestClass.prototype, "clickHandler")
  .callsFake(() => {
    console.log(`Now it's calling the fake handler`);
  });
```

The cleanup would be

```
this.clickHandlerStub.restore();
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mocha-unit-test-example-forked-sstfz?file=/src/index.js

**References:**

- [Restore *sinon* stub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57639139/863110)
- [The idea of stubing *prototype*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56565849/863110)

---

By the way, I prefer not to use `this` in global context. Instead, I'd create them as `let` variables.

```
describe('...', () => {
  let clickHandlerStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    clickHandlerStub = ...
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    clickHandlerStub.restore();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes this seems to work! But according to the [2nd link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091438/jest-how-to-mock-one-specific-method-of-a-class/56565849#56565849), why am i not able to stub the method of the specific instance only?

Comment: I believe you can but you bind the click handler in the constructor so you don't have the chance to stub the method before it's bound. If you would move it out of the constructor you would be able to stub it: https://codesandbox.io/s/mocha-unit-test-example-forked-495sk?file=/src/index.js